# How to get largest, second largest and third largest values from a specific column in datagridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get largest, second largest, third largest number of a particular column (in my case column named Total) which consist of lots of rows, I'm just learning c#, please help me to solve this issue

[image]

## Here i need answer like

I as 276 , 
II as 240, III as 180

I used this code and, its not getting proper output

```
private void btnGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] array = new string[dgConSheet.Rows.Count - 1 + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= dgConSheet.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        array[i] = dgConSheet.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
    }

    Array.Sort(array); //sorting array
    Array.Reverse(array); // Reverse Sorting array value
    MessageBox.Show("Second Highest Value In Array " + array[1]);
}
```

Here Cells[6] is the column total

Comment: You shouldnt use string if you want to sort numbers.

Comment: When it doesn´t get "proper output", what *does* it return?

Comment: Use the source data, not the GridView cell values.

Comment: sir, thanks for your reply

Comment: but it throws error while changing dgConSheet.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString(); dgConSheet.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value;

Comment: @AbelS: are those values `int`s or `string`s? So could you safely cast them to `int`?

Comment: Sir, the data is taking realtime, its not depending on any database, while user input value for J1, J2, J3 then it will calculate total

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: total column contains int values only

Comment: So what does `array` look like after executing your code? What is the **expected** behaviour and what do you get instead?

Comment: Voting to close as we still don´t know the OPs problem.

Comment: Even if the data in the column is of type int, you call `ToString` on it which makes it a `string`. Sorting on strings however doesn´t follow the "natural order of numbers". Thus `2` is greater `11`.

Comment: Converting to string can provide unexpected results. `20 < 100`, but `"20" > "100"` the same way `"ca" > "baa"`

Comment: Thank you guys....I got it in my own way...I just take the total column into an array then i sort it and took the reverse of that array, then i compare it with the elements of total column

Answer (score 1):

You can sort collection and take first 3 elements:

```
string[] res = array.OrderByDescending().Take(3).ToArray();
```

Of course you should be sure that strings you sort are intigers (use int.TryParse if you're not sure).

Comment: as OP stated, there's no need to convert to int since total column is already int. Your answer can be simplified :)